# How to get multiple field values, when a foreign key is called in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a `Attendance` model

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    in_time = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    out_time = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Here is the `Employee` model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    emp_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    epf_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nic_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    appoinment_date = models.DateField()
    termination_date = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bank_branch = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bank_acc_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bank_acc_no = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    active_status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I'm getting data from `Attendance` model

```
attendance_record = Attendance.objects.filter(date = date).values()
```

Here for the `employee` attribute I'm automatically getting the `emp_id` field.But I want to get the `name` field as well
How to do it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the name through the employee relation:

```
attendance_record.employee.name
```

If you want the name in the `attendance_record` queryset, you can use `F('')` expressions.

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Case, Count, F
Attendance.objects.filter(date=date).annotate(name=F('employee__name')).values()
```

Comment: Thanks.. What i wanted was the second option. It worked.

Comment: Do you have the documentation link for that part

Comment: [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) - The documentation isn't clear how F() expressions work from a practicality standpoint.